# Can I get a job if I dont know the local language?

Tags: germany, eu, employment

I am a non-European citizen and I want to work in Germany though I do not understand nor speak nor write German language. I am wanting to know if I can get a job in IT industry if I don't know German. If not in Germany then can I get job in any other European countries? Also I am not staying now in any European countries and I am Asian.

Comment: I think this question is too broad. Is it possible to get a job in Germany speaking only English?  Yes.  Is it easy? No idea.  Check job listings, and see what the requirements are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Berlin there are a large number of IT-based startups in which English is the working language. Depending on your skills you should be able to get a job without too many issues. Bear in mind though that if you're a non EU citizen your job needs to be of a certain level to qualify for a working visa. Also remember that you will need some level of German for day-to-day life, even if the working language at your company is English.

However, to answer the second part of your question, if you're set on the EU and want a job speaking English, then obviously the UK, Ireland and Malta are your obvious choices...

Comment: thanks for answering,I have accepted your answer as the best answer,if you find my question also useful then dont forget to upvote